# Can I remove these braces safely while boarding my garage?

Tags: garage

[image]
Hi everyone

It might be very stupid an amateur question. My apologies in advance. 
I’m boarding my garage to create some space for storage. There are some perpendicular bracing which are attached to wal plates. There are two diagonal ones which are not attached to wall at all. 
I’m putting new joists perpendicular to present ones and these two diagonal braces are on the way. Would it be safe to assume they are remnants of temporary braces and remove them. The roof itself has cross bracing separately. [image]

Comment: What does boarding your garage mean ??

Comment: It is not safe to *assume* that these were intended to be temporary and were not removed. Personally I would leave them in place and work around them. Framing carpenters on this site could explain how to do this. Note that you are adding loads that the roof framing may not be designed for. I think you should get a report from a structural engineer.

Comment: Alaska man I am creating some storage space up there. In doing so I’m putting another layer of joist up there to cover them with loft boarding chip would sheets.

Comment: Hi Jim Stewart thank uou you for your warnings. Building regulations states that:All timber bracing to trussed rafters should be at least 100mm x 25mm in section and twice nailed to each trusses rafter and to the wallplate. Nailing should be 3.35mm (10 gauge) x 65mm long galvanized round
wire nails.
these timbers are not attached to wall plate and possibly should have caused failure of inspection last year if they weee meant as an structural support. But I’ll get the engineers to have a look.

Comment: The diagonals are probably meant to stabilize the bottom chords of your trusses. But the bigger question is about adding weight to a roof system that (typically) isn't designed for that kind of load. Seek engineering help.

Comment: I had a guy for loft boarding. He checked it and said this is designed to take up to 300 kg/m2.